# Git status in XCode never change from 'A'

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4

I don't know what to do, always I do a git commit with XCode, it work but the status of the file is aways 'A' (new file).

If I do the commit from an outside program, it work but don't change the 'A' status in XCode.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Are you actually staging the files and getting them committed? If you clone the repo into another directory, they appear?

Comment: I am committing then. And I am only using a local git. I just create a new project and try to do a commit with XCode. If I use any other git program, it work and the status of the files is normal, but if I open the same project with Xcode, I only get the 'A' status..

Comment: Would a `File -> Source Control -> Refresh Status` display the correct status?

Comment: Yes, I try to refresh various times, but aways it show only the 'A' status.

Answer (score 0):

It may due to any svn working copy committing problem. Just try this, Open terminal and navigate to your project location and just type

```
iMac-03:~ administrator$ svn status
```

it will show the status of the current working copy.

(Note : make sure the location of the working copy is properly rooted) . then execute this

```
 iMac-03:~ administrator$ svn add ./* // This command will connect the non committed files properly with working copy.
```

Comment: Hi. This use git, no svn. But doing this with git, it show that no file has update, but in Xcode, I only see the 'A' status. So this is not a git problem.